# Deny loading of display:none elements in media queries?

Tags: css, cross-platform, media-queries

I have a div with content of 603 KB that is not displayed(`display: none;` in a @media) in resolutions less than 480px (I'm going to implement 320px to optimize for phones later).
I feel sorry for phones having to load 603kb of total waste.

Is a workaround possible?

The temporary and in progress site can be seen on http://www.peterpagh.com/peterpaghdotk/

Comment: You will need to use server-side technologies for this.

Comment: This is not possible with CSS unfortunately.

Comment: @DavidThomas That wouldn't help, images with `display:none` are still downloaded and cached.  His point is that mobile users have to download the images even though they aren't using them.

Comment: Ok i see. I think i will try to scale down the div to be shown in lower res. as  they have loaded it why not make a use of them. scaling  images by using background:contain in a div and adjusting width seems to work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back and approach it from a different direction.

You're hiding content from users that are on a smaller device, so I'm going to guess that the content isn't core to the websites function.

You could use something like https://github.com/filamentgroup/Ajax-Include-Pattern/ to load the content in at a particular breakpoint.

If the content *is* core to the site then you should look at how you can reduce the size.